# How to get dynamic and adaptive timestamp variable in Postman?

Tags: date, datetime, variables, postman

What i need to do is to generate few timestamps: timeNow, +1y ahead and +5years ahead and few other random dates. All that needs to happen in **"Pre-request Script"** for Postman API testing where rRequired format is: *YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.mssZ* which in practice needs to like like *2021-02-24T12:05:35.423Z*

First of all, when i'm trying to use {{$isoTimestamp}} dynamic variable it's not doing nothing which is already frustrating.
Secondly, I've managed to manually create a 'now' date and then concatenated that with 'Z' which already looks like ****

```
const moment = require('moment');    
let eventDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.ms);    
let eventDateTime = eventDate + "Z";
```

So, that gives me time format (the string, actually) I wanted but does not provide any possibility to get those random dates, now+1year and now+5years. I'm kinda new to that so it's breaking my balls, really. Anyone has any idea, pretty please?

Answer (score 2):

**you can get dynamic variables in postman script sessions as :**

```
console.log(pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$isoTimestamp}}"))
```

you should use **replaceIn**

**Also to add something to date use something like:**

**if your start time is in the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss.SSSZ , then use:**

```
const moment = require('moment');

if (pm.info.iteration === 0) {

    pm.collectionVariables.set("startTime", moment.utc())

} else {

    let measuredOnUtc = pm.collectionVariables.get("startTime")

    measuredOnUtc = moment(measuredOnUtc)

    pm.collectionVariables.set("startTime", measuredOnUtc.add(3, 'hours').utc())

}
```

if startime is in format DD-MM-YYYYTHH:MM:ss.SSS[Z] , then use:

```
const moment = require('moment');

if (pm.info.iteration === 0) {

    pm.collectionVariables.set("startTime", moment.utc().format("DD-MM-YYYYTHH:MM:ss.SSS[Z]"))

} else {

    let measuredOnUtc = pm.collectionVariables.get("startTime")

    measuredOnUtc = moment(measuredOnUtc, "DD-MM-YYYYTHH:MM:ss.SSS[Z]")

    pm.collectionVariables.set("startTime", measuredOnUtc.add(3, 'hours').format("DD-MM-YYYYTHH:MM:ss.SSS[Z]"))

}
```

THe request body should be :slight_smile:

```
{

bbla:bla,

"startTime": "{{startTime}}",

bbla:bla
}
```

Comment: Yea, so the`console.log(pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$isoTimestamp}}"))` gives me an error which is saying that replaceIn is not a function (it's a 7.15.1 Postman version, so it might've not been implemented yet). <br />  

When it comes to data addition it's working fine, BUT when I want to `console.log("New Date is: " + newDate)` - then it looses the data format, which is funny, cause `consoloe.log(newDate)` works just fine - when that comment is added then format is re-set to default. <br />  

Also, how do i substract 1 year/month/hour ? :D

Comment: measuredOnUtc.add(3, 'hours') , measuredOnUtc.add(3, 'years ,  measuredOnUtc.add(3, 'days')')

Comment: measuredOnUtc.add(3, 'months')

Comment: update to latest postman why still using old one

Comment: It's corporate software - really don't know, man. I'll try to get an update on that cause the changes are great on that matter. Don't you happen to know how do I *substract* a month ?

Comment: https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/02-subtract/

Comment: please read the documenattion , do accept the answer and upvote by clicking the tick sign and uparow